# PSR4 Sub-directory don't match the case of the sub-namespace names

Tags: php, module, namespaces, magento2, psr-4

According to [psr4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) **sub-directory must match the case of the sub-namespace names**

> The contiguous sub-namespace names after the “namespace prefix” correspond to a subdirectory within a “base directory”, in which the namespace separators represent directory separators. The subdirectory name MUST match the case of the sub-namespace names.

But when I looked under the vendor directory of Magento 2, I have seen different modules whose sub-directory name doesn't match with the sub-namespace names.
For Example: Magento 2 module "**vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting**" used namespace "**Magento\NewRelicReporting**"

But when I try to do develop the module followed the Magento 2 approach, **I failed**

1. Create a vendor folder named "**aneeqtariq143**"
2. Create a module name "**magento2-product-newsletter**"
3. Create a **composer.json** file with the content

```
        {
        "name": "aneeqtariq143/magento2-module-magento2-product-newsletter",
        "require": {
            "php": "~7.0.0"
        },
        "type": "magento2-module",
        "autoload": {
           "files": [
             "registration.php"
            ],
         "psr-4": {
             "Aneeqtariq143\\Magento2ProductNewsletter\\": ""
           }
         }
        }
```

4. Create a controller with namespace

```
namespace Aneeqtariq143\Magento2ProductNewsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;
```

- It didn't work.

  - Magento can't find my controller.
- Also, point me to the best practices for module directory naming convention and namespaces.

Comment: It helps to be a bit more specific in the title for faster responses. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand how Magento handles this. Assuming you have no problems caused by the routes.xml files in `etc/frontend` or `etc/adminhtml`. The name you have given in the composer.json file `aneeqtariq143/magento2-module-magento2-product-newsletter` would say your namespace should be `Aneeqtariq143\\Magento2ModuleMagento2ProductNewsletter\\`. Magento seems to expect you to use `module-<modulename>` not `magento2-module-<modulename>`.

It would be worth checking that your url targeting the controller conforms to (in your case) `<frontname(./etc/adminhtml/routes.xml)>/Adminhtml/Product` anyway.